# How to protect a high-voltage output stage from very high transients

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, transient-suppression, mov, switching-transients

Usually in electronics, one can use MOV or TVS diodes to get rid of voltage transients. That's because most applications run at a voltage of 500 V or less.

But assume I want to protect the output module of my high voltage generator (40 kV) from very high transients (> 60 kV), that occur, say, during sparking. These will kill the output capacitors of the generator.

After getting my capacitor burnt, my only solution was to put three 40 kV rated capacitors in series, which gives a theoretical breakdown voltage of 120 kV. This worked during a while, but they finally burnt too.

It should be theoretically possible to put hundreds of TVS in series, but I don't think that's a viable solution.

I'm asking if there is a dedicated high-voltage device, homologous to a TVS or a MOV, for this kind of job. Alternatively, I'm asking if there is a clever circuit method that would help in these circumstances.

Schematic of my output module:

[image: HV output module]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140461/discussion-on-question-by-miketex-how-to-protect-a-high-voltage-output-stage-fro).

Answer (score 0):

As for an answer to the general part of the question, the comment of brahns was found to be useful:

*Gaz discharge arrestors* are indeed a dedicated device to stop high voltage transients, with breakdown voltage of up to 10 kV (as far as I could check).
They can be put in series to obtain a greater breakdown voltage.

I thought those were rather uncommon expensive parts which were produced by few specialized companies, so I was surprised to discover that they are in fact commonly available and cheap parts, even Aliexpress or Ebay have plenty of sellers at 1$ pcs or less.
Here are some pics from Aliexpress:

[image: gaz arrestor examples]

Comment: Do you really want to trust a high voltage component like that to AliExpress or EBay? Do they even provide datasheets for them?

Comment: @DKNguyen. Most likely no. But they have good pics and that exemplifies the fact that these parts are quite of common use (otherwise, these markets would not sell them such extensively). This being said, there are some serious sellers there. That's a matter of knowing where to buy.

Comment: The problem with gas clamps is they're very slow compared to a TVS but can handle alot of energy.   Its reasonable to put multiple different protections in parallel.

Comment: @Kyle B. Yeah, I've think about that too. I'm not sure they are sufficiently fast to protect caps from being killed. At the least, I think they may help...

Comment: putting caps in series like that doesn't work in general -- because different capacitors may have slightly different leakage currents, there is no guarantee that the voltage will share equally across them.

Answer (score 0):

A spark gap is the classic approach at these kind of levels.